# Response.Redirect with Different Referrer

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect, referrer, referer

I've got the following piece of code in an aspx webpage:

```
Response.Redirect("/Someurl/");
```

I also want to send a different referrer with the redirect something like:

```
Response.Redirect("/Someurl/", "/previousurl/?message=hello");
```

Is this possible in Asp.net or is the referrer handled solely by the browser?

Cheers
Stephen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referrer is readonly and meant to be that way. I do not know why you need that but you can send query variables as instead of

```
Response.Redirect("/Someurl/");
```

you can call

```
Response.Redirect("/Someurl/?message=hello");
```

and get what you need there, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`Response.Redirect` sends an answer code (HTTP 302) to the browser which in turn issues a new request (at least this is the expected behavior). Another possibility is to use `Server.Transfer` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer.aspx)) which doesn't go back to the browser.
Anyway, both of them don't solve your request. Perhaps giving some more detail on your case can help find another solution. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The referrer comes solely from the client browser (which may be lying to you, too)